# Problem creating a web service from a WSDL

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, netbeans6.8

The problem I'm having is that when I attempt to create a web service in netbeans using this wsdl, netbeans says that there is no service defined. I'm new to the whole wsdl thing but as far as I can tell there is one defined.

The wsdl is:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"  xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tns="http://discoveryinsurance.com/DicQuoteSvc/AgencyQuote.wsdl" xmlns:ns="http://discoveryinsurance.com/DicQuoteSvc/schemas/DicAcordQuoteRq.xsd" xmlns:na="http://discoveryinsurance.com/DicQuoteSvc/schemas/DicAcordQuoteRs.xsd" targetNamespace="http://discoveryinsurance.com/DicQuoteSvc/AgencyQuote.wsdl">
<wsdl:import namespace="http://discoveryinsurance.com/DicQuoteSvc/schemas/" location="DicAcordQuoteRq.xsd"/>
<wsdl:import namespace="http://discoveryinsurance.com/DicQuoteSvc/schemas/" location="DicAcordQuoteRs.xsd"/>
<wsdl:types>
    <xs:schema targetNamespace="http://discoveryinsurance.com/DicQuoteSvc/schemas/" elementFormDefault="qualified"/>
</wsdl:types>
<wsdl:message name="NewMessageRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="parameter" element="ns:ACORD"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="NewMessageResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="parameter" element="na:ACORD"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:portType name="QuotePortType">
    <wsdl:operation name="RequestQuote">
        <wsdl:input message="tns:NewMessageRequest"/>
        <wsdl:output message="tns:NewMessageResponse"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:binding name="QuoteBinding" type="tns:QuotePortType">
    <soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="RequestQuote">
        <soap:operation soapAction="http://discoveryinsurance.com/DicQuoteSvc/AgencyQuote" style="rpc"/>
        <wsdl:input>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="AgencyQuote">
    <wsdl:port name="QuotePortType" binding="tns:QuoteBinding">
        <soap:address  location="http://discoveryinsurance.com/DicQuoteSvc/"/>
    </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```

XMLSpy says that the wsdl is valid but it fails when i try to create the web service from it.
Any help would be appreciated even constructive criticism.

**EDIT**

Using wsimport from the commmand line I get.

> [ERROR] Invalid wsdl:operation "RequestQuote": its a rpc-literal operation,  mes
>   sage part must refer to a schema type declaration
>     line 16 of file:/D:/projects/DICACORD/QuoteRq2.wsdl

Does that mean that even though the two xsd's are imported I still have to define the types in the wsdl?

**Update 2**

The schema for the request->.
[Schema at pastie](http://pastie.org/747795)

**Addition**

Does anyone see anything wrong with the xsd imports and/or how they are being used?

Comment: What framework are you working in.  Spring makes this very easy.

Comment: ALSO, where is your XSD? (schema)

Comment: the schemas are well over 250 lines each. will it allow me to post ones that large?

Comment: Hmmm... is using Spring an Option?  Is so I could point you in the direction of a question that will show you the entire setup.  I could also point you towards a tutorial... spring is great because it will make the WSDL for you on the fly.

Comment: @Zoidberg Come on, Spring won't solve anything here. This is a not a WS stack problem... And some people do want to use a WSDL-first approach (JAX-WS can generate a WSDL too though).

Comment: Unfortunately for me, Spring is not an option for this particular project.

Comment: @ChadNC Maybe you could use http://pastie.org/ for your XSDs

Comment: I copy/pasted the schema from xmlspy. I dunno why it added so many tab spaces to it.

Comment: @Pascal Thanks for mentioning pastie.org. I added a link to the schema using that site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question, the reason the web service was failing to be created from the wsdl was due to the use of`wsdl:import` instead of `xs:import`.

I didn't know it but after doing some more research it seems that wsdl:import should be used when you want to import another wsdl but if you want to import a schema from a to use the types defined in it within the wsdl you need to use an `xsd:import` because if not wsimport will not find the types defined in the schema.

I changed

```
xmlns:ns="http://discoveryinsurance.com/DicQuoteSvc/schemas/DicAcordQuoteRq.xsd"
xmlns:na="http://discoveryinsurance.com/DicQuoteSvc/schemas/DicAcordQuoteRs.xsd"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
```

to

```
xmlns:rq="http://discoveryinsurance.com/DicQuoteSvc/schemas/request/" 
xmlns:rs="http://discoveryinsurance.com/DicQuoteSvc/schemas/response/"
```

and changed the imports from

```
<wsdl:import namespace="http://discoveryinsurance.com/DicQuoteSvc/schemas/"  location="DicAcordQuoteRq.xsd"/>
<wsdl:import namespace="http://discoveryinsurance.com/DicQuoteSvc/schemas/" location="DicAcordQuoteRs.xsd"/>
```

to

```
<xs:import namespace="http://discoveryinsurance.com/DicQuoteSvc/schemas/request/" schemaLocation="DicAcordQuoteRq.xsd"/>
<xs:import namespace="http://discoveryinsurance.com/DicQuoteSvc/schemas/response/" schemaLocation="DicAcordQuoteRs.xsd"/>
```

Making these changes allowed the web service to build successfully and the classes were created based off of the two schemas. Hopefully when I begin testing the web service on Monday it will work as I want it to. Thanks all of you for the input you provided as it led me to look into other reasons why the creation of the web service from the wsdl was failing.

I did change the namespace that they are in but that was for different reasons and I did that after the web service had been created and deployed locally on my machine.

Happy Holidays Everyone.

Answer (score 5):

Easiest way to verify that wsdl is valid is to run from command line:

```
wsimport yourservice.wsdl
```

and see if it gives you any errors. wsimport comes with JDK 1.6

WSDL you submitted is not complete as it has references to external schema files (XSD) so there is no way for me to validate it.

Answer (score 0):

ACORD is in the namespace `http://discoveryinsurance.com/DicQuoteSvc/schemas/DicAcordQuoteRq.xsd`.

It seems to me that your import of ACORD is invalid, in that it is identifying ACORD's namespace differently:

> `<wsdl:import namespace="http://discoveryinsurance.com/DicQuoteSvc/schemas/" location="DicAcordQuoteRq.xsd"/>`